# Expected value of $\sin^2(0.01n)$ for discrete $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to calculate the expected value of $\sin^2(0.01n)$, with $n$ taking non-negative integer values?

Normally, when we wish to find the expected value of the sine function, we integrate (or add) its corresponding values within a single period (I think?), and then take its mean. Is such a method possible for the function under question?

Comment: What is the distribution of $n$?

Comment: It is uniformly distributed. This is actually the input signal to a wiener filter, and I am trying to find its wiener solution.

Comment: There is no such thing as a uniformly distributed integer. Uniform (discrete) distributions are on *finite* sets, not on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: So... how should I put it then? The number of values obtained depends on how long I sample the function... .

Comment: The only way to define a probability distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ is to assign probabilities to every positive integer, i.e., a sequence of non-negative numbers that add up to $1$. This is the only way you can put it. However you try to define uniform distribution, it will fail, as it is absurd.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *Disclaimer: This is, so far, one of my most downvoted answers on the site. Since it is perfectly correct, and it answers the question, the downvotes might be due to some extra-mathematical reasons. In any case... happy reading!*

The phrase "expected value" has no meaning when applied to a sequence $\mathbf x=(x_n)_{n\geqslant1}$, but one can look at the *Cesàro means* $(c_n(\mathbf x))_{n\geqslant1}$ and at their limit $\mathcal C(\mathbf x)$ defined, if it exists, as $$\mathcal C(\mathbf x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n(\mathbf x)$$ where, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$c_n(\mathbf x)=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$$
In the present case, $x_n=\sin^2(an)$ with $a=0.01$ hence $2x_n=1-\cos(2an)=1-\Re(\mathrm e^{\mathrm ian})$ and $$2c_n(\mathbf x)=1-\frac1n\Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm e^{\mathrm iak}\right)$$ 
The sum in the RHS is geometric with ratio $z=\mathrm e^{\mathrm ia}$. Thus, the sums in the RHS are bounded since $|z|=1$ and $z\ne1$, hence the sequence $(c_n(\mathbf x))_{n\geqslant1}$ converges and its limit is $$\mathcal C(\mathbf x)=\frac12$$

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Let me add one back.

Comment: @Jack Thanks. I guess we have to live with such erratic behaviours. :-)